# Xamarin Android passing data between views

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am new to Xamarin Android. I am looking to create a multi-step registration form i.e. wizard process. 
I am seeking for some best practises on a approach that can save each step state in order to build up a model and then submit the model (Builder design pattern).

I am not sure how to save a state when going to another view. From research, would i pass a view model as part of the intent by calling PutExtra to pass data ? 

I am not sure what is the good way doing this. I am using MVVMCross for building up the viewmodel. I hope the community can assist me on the right direction please

Answer (score 1):

In MvvmCross you don't pass data between views, but all navigation is done between ViewModels. Extensive documentation about this can be found at: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation

An example is:

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;
    public MyViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public override void Prepare()
    {
        //Do anything before navigating to the view
    }

    public async Task SomeMethod()
    {
        await _navigationService.Navigate<NextViewModel, MyObject>(new MyObject());
    }
}

public class NextViewModel : MvxViewModel<MyObject>
{
    public override void Prepare(MyObject parameter)
    {
        //Do anything before navigating to the view
        //Save the parameter to a property if you want to use it later
    }

    public override async Task Initialize()
    {
        //Do heavy work and data loading here
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the best way to pass data for each steps i.e. registration wizard where each steps would be passed into last step in order to aggregate the full model ?